# Android parseException unparseable date in specific devices?

Tags: android, date-format, android-2.2-froyo, date-conversion, parseexception

In my android App I am converting a string to a date using the following method

```
public Date convertToDate(String date) {  //(input date format "Feb 18, 2013 01:32 AM")
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.SHORT);
        try {  
            Date dateObj = dateFormat.parse(date);
            return dateObj;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Utility", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

It works fine in most of the mobile but for some reason it's not working in 2.2 version devices and some samsung devies and **throwing parse Exception unparseable date**. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use simpledateformat for your code..

```
 SimpleDateFormat dfDate  = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm a");
 try {
    dateObj  = dfDate.parse(date);
} catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: SimpleDateFormat does the job, just add a Locale argument to avoid language related issues: SimpleDateFormat(yourString,Locale.YOUR_COUNTRY)

Comment: this also throws the same exception no change.

Comment: the problem is with extra space after `a`. I removed it. now check once

Comment: MMM dd, yyyy h:mm aa this format did the trick with both of @user1527232 and Ram Kiran solution thanks guys :)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html